# How to serve images with nginx

Tags: configuration, nginx, configuration-files

I am completely new to nginx and I am asked to find a way to serve Map Tiles that are separated according to the zoom levels. The image file structure is like `~/data/images/7/65/70.png` where 7 is the zoom level, 65 and 70 are the lon-lat values. The folder 65 contains many files such as 71.png, 72.png and etc.

I have installed Nginx properly and I can get `Welcome to nginx` message. I have followed the instructions in `http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html` and created the `/data/www` and `/data/images` directories. I have placed index.html file under `/data/www` and tile images under `/data/images`. Then I modified the configuration file by adding following lines in http tags:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /data/www;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
}
```

After reloading the config file and entering localhost on the browser I can neither get the index.html file nor see the images.

What I am trying to do is to display the image when I enter something as:

```
http://localhost/1.0.0/basemap/7/65/70.png
```

- 7: folder indicating 7th zoom level
- 65: folder indicating the latitude
- 70.png: file indicating the longitude (folder 65 includes many png files)

What am I missing?

Comment: why create a new server block, what is the URL that you are planning to access these images by, are they still localhost or do you have a domain that points to your server

Comment: they are localhost. there is no domain. I created the new server block because the beginner's guide says so

Comment: do you have a `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` folder inside `/etc/nginx` ?

Comment: Yes, those folders are inside `/etc/nginx` and both have `default` file inside. I also edited the OP, please check

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, let me explain something, you already have a localhost server, which is defined inside a file called `default` that is the file that causes the "Welcome to nginx" or something to appear, and I believe you can't create a new server with the same `server_name`, let's remove that and make your localhost serve only those images,

- First we need to delete the `default` file from `sites-enabled` , it will still exist inside `sites-available` if you ever want to get it back. *( note that all files inside `sites-enabled` are simply symlinks from the files inside `sites-available` )*
- We create a new file inside `sites-available` and call it whatever you want, `images-app` for example
- create the new server inside the `images-app` file, I'll assume that the root of the app is inside a folder called `/data` of course you will map that to your own server structure.

  ```
  server {
      server_name localhost;
      root /data;
      index index.html;
      location / {
          try_files $uri =404;
      }
  }
  ```
- now we go to `sites-enabled` and enable this site we created inside `sites-available`

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/images-app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
  ```
- make sure that all the nginx config are correct

  ```
  sudo nginx -t
  ```
- If nothing is wrong we can go ahead and reload nginx settings

  ```
  sudo service nginx reload
  ```

Comment: This is very detailed and instructive. I had to delete my virtual machine due to disk error. I am now re-installing it and will try it when installation is done. Thank you very much

Comment: I have just had the chance to try this out and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the detailed answer and your time

Comment: or just modify this `default` file already having half of the instruction to set up your own server.

Answer (score 10):

For my case I just edited `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file.

I added following config:

```
location /images/ {
            root /data;
        }
```

and placed images under `/data/images`:

[image]

and url works: http://localhost/images/example.png

I use VS Code as SuperUser. (I know it is bad, but I accept risks)
It helps a lot with root access file editing:

[image]

Comment: can i create image hosting service with ngnix? and custom domain ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm also new to nginx, Here is my solution that is similar with Mohammad AbuShady's answer :

- delete `sites-enabled/default`
- create the `whatever.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

The reason is:

#### `sites-enabled/default` has defined a server

that is listening on 80 rooting with /var/www/html

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;
  location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

#### the `nginx.conf` file includes other conf files

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

#### pay attention on permission

the 1st edition of my.conf is root on /home/myusername/, but will get 403 Forbidden error, check the error.log:

```
2016/04/07 20:12:44 [error] 12466#0: *2 open() "/home/myusername/data/a" failed (13: Permission denied), 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /a HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```