# Vue production images folder is not updating?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx

I have a vue web app where you can upload images. When I was creating it, I was running it on localhost with *hot-reload* on.

However, when I hosted my app at digitalocean and used this command (`npm run build`) I faced a problem. As far as I understand it, **vue had built my app, and then started ignoring new files.**

*I've already tried to put the uploads folder outside of vue app* but it didn't help me.

> How to upload images and dynamically be able to access them?

By the way my stack is: Vue.js (frontend), Laravel (backend) and nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vue frontend has to be built (creating a "dist" folder) every time you wish to see a change.

Either host the images on your DigitalOcean droplet or a database.

Simple way to accomplish self-hosting of the images with 2 APIs (POST, GET):

**1.** Send image frontend -> backend

**2.** Save image backend -> droplet
(parse the image with Laravel and save to a directory on your server)

**3.** Send image backend -> frontend OR use image's location on the server as your "src" (whichever method is necessary in your app)

---

Or serve your images using nginx: [How to serve images with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954827/how-to-serve-images-with-nginx)

Comment: You mean I have to locate uploads folder outside of the project? My project is located in /var/www/html/project/

Comment: you can upload it to for example /var/projectFiles or something

Comment: It didn't help me. The file was successfully uploaded, but vue client can't see it

Comment: If youre using nginx, then follow this thread to serve images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954827/how-to-serve-images-with-nginx